# Import custom Java class

Tags: java, import

I'm new to Java and I've looked around the web for solutions but none seem to work.  Please help me.

I have two files.  One of them is the java file that contains the main function.  In it:

```
...
VaporVisitor visitor = new VaporVisitor();
...
```

With that command, I want to create a new object `VaporVisitor`, which is a class in a separate file called `VaporVisitor.java`.  However Java doesn't recognize what VaporVisitor is, presumably because it doesn't know `VaporVisitor.java` exists (it's in the same directory).  I tried making them part of the same package, in different packages and importing...and all of them failed.  Can anyone give me any guidance?

Thanks!

EDIT: Here's exactly what I'm doing, and the error message I get:
So I have 3 files.  V2VM (with my main function), VaporVisitor, and a provided jar file that has several custom classes.  The jar file isn't giving me any problems; it's trying to get java to recognize VaporVisitor.

So in V2VM (the main function), I've tried putting in: `import V2VM.java;` which didn't work.  I've tried putting V2VM in a subfolder called vv, added `package vv;` to VaporVisitor and put in V2VM.java `import vv.*` but that didn't work either.

For compiling, I tried `javac -classpath [the jar file].jar V2VM.java`

The errors it gives me:

```
V2VM.java:15: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class VaporVisitor
location: class V2VM
VaporVisitor visitor = new VaporVisitor();
^
V2VM.java:15: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class VaporVisitor
location: class V2VM
VaporVisitor visitor = new VaporVisitor();
                           ^
```

When I run `javacc` I am in the same directory as V2VM, which is also where the other two files are located.  I've tried putting V2VM and VaporVisitor in the same package, but that didn't work either. So they are not part of any package now...

EDIT 2: SOURCE CODE OF VaporVisitor and V2VM

V2VM.java:

```
package vv; //whether I put this or not, it doesn't work

//this stuff was provided, and is related to importing contents of the jar file; don't think this is the problem
import cs132.util.ProblemException;
import cs132.vapor.parser.VaporParser;
import cs132.vapor.ast.VaporProgram;
import cs132.vapor.ast.VBuiltIn.Op;

import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintStream;

import vv.VaporVisitor;  //whether I put this or not, it doesn't work

public class V2VM{

public static void main(String [] args){

VaporProgram vp = parseVapor(System.in, System.err);
VaporVisitor visitor = new VaporVisitor();

for(int i=0; i<vp.functions.length; i++){
for(int j=0; j<vp.functions[i].body.length; j++){
    vp.functions[i].body[j].accept(parameter, visitor);
    }
}
}

public static VaporProgram parseVapor(InputStream in, PrintStream err){
  ...
}
```

For VaporVisitor.java:

```
package vv;

public class VaporVisitor extends VInstr.VisitorPR<Parameter_Type, Return_Type, RuntimeException>{
   ....
}
```

All 3 files are in the same directory `vv`

Comment: How are you compiling? (An IDE would normally sort all of this out for you, for example.)

Comment: How do you compile those classes. Show us thedirectories where the files are placed, the directory where you are, and the command used to compile the files. Paste the exact error message you have. Tell us in which package the classes are.

Comment: I'm actually using the terminal and just running `javac`.  It'd be great if I could understand what I should be doing instead of relying on the IDE if possible

Comment: The directory and the package must match. Anyway, are you sure that `VaporVisitor` is compiling correctly?

Comment: Edit your question, and answer *every* question I asked.

Comment: Begin with an IDE to ensure that the classes are ok, then you can try to learn how to use the command line.

Comment: Only issue is improper import statement seems couldn find your class at al.. Use import vv.VaporVisitor; on your import

Comment: @ATR do i have to put VaporVisitor in a subdirectory `vv`?

Comment: yes obviously :) @pauliwago

Comment: @ATR I did that, and I get an additional error `V2VM.java:6: package vv does not exist
import vv.VaporVisitor;`

Comment: I've put `package vv` in VaporVisitor, and put the actual file int he subdirectory `vv` :(

Answer (score 10, accepted):

OK. So first of all, you never refer to a class in Java by appending `.java` to its name. Second: in order to compile a class A that uses another class B, the class B must be compiled, and available in the classpath. Or you must compile both A and B at the same time.

So, you should have the following structure:

```
project
   lib
      someFile.jar
   src
      vv
         V2VM.java
         VaporVisitor.java
   classes
```

Both classes should start with:

```
 package vv;
```

There's no need to import V2VM in VaporVisitor or vice versa, since they are in the same package.

To compile the files, you should be in the project directory, and use the following command:

```
javac -cp lib/someFile.jar -d classes src/vv/V2VM.java src/vv/VaporVisitor.java
```

This will compile the two files at once, and put their compiled class files in project/classes:

```
project
   classes
      vv
         V2VM.class
         VaporVisitor.class
```

You put the jar file in the classpath because the classes you compile use classes from this jar file.

Then, to run your class, you need to have both the jar file, and the classes directory in the classpath. And the fully qualified name of the main class is `vv.V2VM`. So the command is

```
java -cp lib/someFile.jar:classes vv.V2VM
```

If you're on windows, you must use `\` instead of `/`, and `;` instead of `:`.

If you wanted to compile VaporVisiotr first, and then V2VM, you could. But then you would have to do the following:

```
javac -cp lib/someFile.jar -d classes src/vv/VaporVisitor.java
```

This compiles VaporVisiotr only, and put its class file in `project/classes`. Then you need to compile V2VM, which depends on VaporVisitor. So the compiled VaporVisitor class must be available in the classpath. So the command is

```
javac -cp lib/someFile.jar:classes -d classes src/vv/V2VM.java
```

If you decided to put VaporVisitor in another package (`vv.foo` for example), then you would need the following structure:

```
project
   lib
      someFile.jar
   src
      vv
         V2VM.java
         foo
             VaporVisitor.java
   classes
```

The VaporVisitor.java would need to start with

```
package vv.foo;
```

And the V2VM.java file would need to have

```
package vv;
import vv.foo.VaporVisitor;
```

Read the [tutorial about packages](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/index.html).