# why not recognize the array object

Tags: android, arrays, web-services, connection

Why Android Studio not recognize the array object,   the array private `DatoUsuario[] listarUsuario`;

Here is the Android Error

> "Error: (85, 17) can not find symbol class "DatoUsuario"

```
private class WSConsulta extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Boolean>
{
    private DatoUsuario[] listarUsuario;

            listarUsuario = new DatoUsuario[resSoap.getPropertyCount()];

            for (int i = 0; i < listarUsuario.length; i++)
            {
                SoapObject ic = (SoapObject)resSoap.getProperty(i);
                DatoUsuario usuario = new DatoUsuario();
                usuario.idUsuario = Integer.parseInt(ic.getProperty(0).toString());
                usuario.nombreUsuario = ic.getProperty(1).toString();
                usuario.idEstudiante = Integer.parseInt(ic.getProperty(2).toString());
                usuario.nombre = ic.getProperty(3).toString();
                usuario.cedula = ic.getProperty(4).toString();
                usuario.idCarrera = Integer.parseInt(ic.getProperty(5).toString());
                usuario.carrera = ic.getProperty(ic.getProperty(6).toString());
                usuario.codCarrera = Integer.parseInt(ic.getProperty(7).toString());
                usuario.mensaje = ic.getProperty(8).toString();


     }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No hay Conexion con el WS: " + e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //txtConexion.setText("No hay Conexion con el WS");
        return result = false;
    }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post working code - you seem to be missing a `try`, for instance. Furthermore, are you sure you have imported your `DatoUsuario` class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Cannot find class` error occurs when the compiler is not able to recognize an object. To fix this, you need to import the class `DatoUsuario` like this:

```
import packageName.DatoUsuario;
```

For more info, visit [Importing Custom Class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13657918/3886922).