# Import our own classes in java

Tags: java, import, package

OK here is the deal: I have a "run" class that runs my main code. Then I have a class named "mathematics" that has all my calculations in it. Now I want to import  "mathematics" into "run". How can I do that. I have already tried this way:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.*;
import java.math.*;
import mathematics;

public class run {
    public static void main (String[] args){
        System.out.println(power(4.0, 2));

    }
    public static double piCalculator (double x){
        return Math.PI * x;
    }
    public static double power (double x, int y){
        double z = 1;
        for (int n = 0; n < y; n++){
            z = (z * x);
        }
        return z;
    }

}
```

So please tell me how can I do this. Here are the pictures.
[complete code sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lwePk.png)

Comment: With your setup, you shouldn't need to import.  It appears to be in the same package and should already be able to be referenced.  Also note that you can put multiple classes in the same file and have them reference eachother

Comment: Please conform to Java coding conventions: Type names (class,interface,enum) should start with a capital letter (e.g. `BigPicture`) and have no underscores. Method, variable and field names should start with a lowercase letter (e.g. `bigPicture`) and have no underscores, and constants should be all-caps (e.g. `BIG_PICTURE`). Package names are lowercase.

Comment: Here you go:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13657787/import-custom-java-class

Answer (score 2):

No need to import the mathematics class.
Just create an object from the class mathematics and use it.

```
Mathematics math = new Mathematics();
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your classes into package (for ex., main). Then import them like this:

```
import main.mathematics;
```

P.S. Call classes with a capital letter.

Answer (score 0):

This is very easy to do. If you are in Eclipse, assuming they are in the same package, they should automatically be included; otherwise, you can simply include this line at the top:

`import yourClassName;`

If they are in a separate package, you can include all classes in the package by the following:

`import your.package.name;`