# Spring annotation @Inject doesn't work

Tags: java, spring

I have the code `@Inject` works in one class but not in other.
Here's my code:

- context.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"

       xsi:schemaLocation=" http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
                    ">
    <bean id="multipartResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver"></bean>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.myfashions.services"/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.myfashions.dao"/>
</beans>
```

- SellerRetriever.java

```java
public class SellerRetriever {
    @Inject
    UserDAO userDAO;
    ...
    ...
}
```

`UserDAO` class is present in `com.myfashions.dao` package.
`@Inject` is not working in Seller.java. Any reason why?

Comment: Is the `Seller` class Spring managed?  Or are you creating it with the `new` operator?

Comment: Thanks @nicholas.hauschild u made me know my mistake. I created that object with new operator. So that was the reason i got all the injects null

Comment: `@Inject` is not a spring annotation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found my mistake, I'm posting this because in case anyone has the same problem. I used new operator to create an SellerRetriver object. Inject won't work if new operator is used to call that particular class.

Answer (score 7):

Make sure that both `SellerRetriever` and the implementation of `UserDAO` are annotated for the component scan. This will ensure that the latter is injected into the former:

```
@Service
public class SellerRetriever {
    @Inject
    UserDAO userDAO;
    ...
}
```

Annotate the `UserDAO` implementation with `@Component`.

When scanning multiple paths use:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.myfashions.services, com.myfashions.dao"/>
```

Comment: UserDAO is getting injected in other service classes but not in SellerRetriever.java

Comment: I assume that `SellerRetriever` in `com.myfashions.services`. Try using a single component scan tag in your application context

Comment: @Reimeus That's an interesting suggestion.  Could Spring do the first component scan and miss `UserDAO` because it doesn't get around to it until the second component scan?

Comment: @davidfmatheson TBH both are equivalent, just a preference. Suspect that problem here _could possibly be_ an old class version. A rebuild should determine if that is the case

Answer (score 3):

To be eligible to scan, your class must be annotated with either a more generic `@Component`, or `@Service` or `@Repositories` etc.. In your case, `@Service` logically better fits.
You could then (if you need) define some aspects (AOP) focused specifically on services call.

Besides, you may want to use `@Autowired` instead of `@Inject` to retrieve your bean.

For more information about differences concerning these two annotations:

[What is the difference between @Inject and @Autowired in Spring Framework? Which one to use under what condition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7142622/what-is-the-difference-between-inject-and-autowired-in-spring-framework-which)

and you can see my comment just below explaining one good reason to keep `@Autowired` instead of `@Inject`.

Comment: Its a great answer, but still I'm getting NullPointerException.

Comment: I thought you could use either `@Inject` or `@Autowired` in conjunction with `component-scan`... as long as you're using Spring 3.

Comment: add @Component or @ Service or @ Repositories above your class declaration, otherwise it would be not scanned.

Comment: @Mik378 describe you answer in more detail. I do not agree with you.

Comment: @Michal Boreck Yes, indeed we could use `@Inject` since Spring 3. But in order to fit the standard way, we commonly may use `@Autowired`.

Comment: There is no `standard` way. There is only the new way and the old one.

Comment: @Michal Borek Take the case of an application using Spring 2. Since `@Inject`(JSR-299) and `@Autowired` (owning by Spring even before the third version) behave identically, when we want to upgrade Spring 2 to Spring 3, two scenarios:  blending `@Autowired` with `@Inject`, replacing all `@Autowired` by `@Inject`, or continue using `@Autowired`. In a huge project, I think that the cleanest and effortless way is to continue using `@Autowired`, in order to make Spring 3 upgrade more transparent to user.

Comment: @Mik378 That's one use case, legacy support between Spring 2 & 3.  The question doesn't mention such a requirement, but OK.  There are other things that might drive you away from `@Autowired`, such as a desire to wire beans up by name using annotations.  In this case Spring recommends that you use `@Resource` (http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-annotation-config).  You might also want to move towards a Java standard (like `@Inject`) in case you switch to a different dependency injection framework down the line.

Comment: @davidfmatheson I agree with you.

Comment: Since `@Inject` is a java annotation, and `@Autowired` is spring depdendant, `@Inject` has an advantage if you ever want to change DI-framework.