# Adding applicationproperties in Jhipster

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jhipster

I'm using jhipster microservices app for my development. Based on jhipster documentation for adding application-specific is here:
[application-dev.yml](https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-sample-app/blob/master/src/main/resources/config/application-dev.yml)  and
[ApplicationProperties.java](https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-sample-app/blob/master/src/main/java/io/github/jhipster/sample/config/ApplicationProperties.java)

I did this by adding this

```
application:
      mycom:
        sgADIpAddress: 172.x.x.xxx
```

and this my applicationconfig class

```
package com.mbb.ias.config;

 import   org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;



  /**
    * Properties specific to JHipster.
     *
    * <p>
    *     Properties are configured in the application.yml file.
    * </p>
    */
   @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "application",  ignoreUnknownFields     = false)
public class ApplicationProperties {

private final Mycom mycom= new Mycom();



public Mycom getMycom () {
    return mycom;
}



public static class Mycom {
    String sgADIpAddress ="";

    public String getSgADIpAddress() {
        return sgADIpAddress;
    }

    public void setSgADIpAddress(String sgADIpAddress) {
        this.sgADIpAddress = sgADIpAddress;
    }

}
```

}

I've call this by using same like jhipster properties which are

```
    @Inject
    private ApplicationProperties applicationProperties;
```

in classes which are need this AD IP address.

it will throw null value

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
```

please help me guys, SIT going to be started, I need to create a profile for maven build like jhipster created

Comment: Have you tried adding a setter for your mycom field instead of calling the constructor?

Comment: i did but i didnt require the setter for mycom.  can see this sample from jhipster itself   https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-registry/blob/master/src/main/java/io/github/jhipster/registry/config/JHipsterProperties.java

Comment: @rob and Han. I have posted my solution, please take a look:)

Answer (score 5):

I have the same problem and spent a couple of hours to figure it out...Jhipster has its preconfigured property class that users can customize their own properteis:

Quote from Jhipster website:

> Your generated application can also have its own Spring Boot properties. This is highly recommended, as it allows type-safe configuration of the application, as well as auto-completion and documentation within an IDE.
>
> JHipster has generated a ApplicationProperties class in the config package, which is already preconfigured, and it is already documented at the bottom the application.yml, application-dev.yml and application-prod.yml files. All you need to do is code your own specific properties.

In my case, I have set the properties in all yml files.

```
application:
    redis:
        host: vnode1
        pool:
            max-active: 8
            max-idle: 8
            max-wait: -1
            min-idle: 0
        port: 6379
```

In ApplicationProperties class:

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "application", ignoreUnknownFields = false)
public class ApplicationProperties {

    public final Redis redis = new Redis();

    public Redis getRedis() {
        return redis;
    }

    public static class Redis {

        private String host = "127.0.0.1";

        private int port = 0;

        public String getHost() {
            return host;
        }

        public void setHost(String host) {
            this.host = host;
        }

        public int getPort() {
            return port;
        }

        public void setPort(int port) {
            this.port = port;
        }

        private Pool pool = new Pool();

        public void setPool(Pool pool) {
            this.pool = pool;
        }

        public Pool getPool() {
            return this.pool;
        }

        public static class Pool {
            private int maxActive = 8;
            private int maxWait = -1;
            private int maxIdle = 8;
            private int minIdle = 0;


            public int getMaxIdle() {
                return maxIdle;
            }

            public void setMaxIdle(int maxIdle) {
                this.maxIdle = maxIdle;
            }   

            public void setMaxActive(int maxActive) {
                this.maxActive = maxActive;
            }

            public int getMaxActive() {
                return maxActive;
            }

            public int getMinIdle() {
                return minIdle;
            }

            public void setMinIdle(int minIdle) {
                this.minIdle = minIdle;
            }

            public int getMaxWait() {
                return maxWait;
            }

            public void setMaxWait(int maxWait) {
                this.maxWait = maxWait;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Then I use it as:

```
private final ApplicationProperties.Redis redis;
public RedisConfiguration(ApplicationProperties applicationProperties){
    redis = applicationProperties.getRedis();
}
```

For instance use `max-wait` and `host`:

```
this.redis.getPool().getMaxWait();
this.redis.getHost();
```

Answer (score 2):

refering to this thread
[Spring annotation @Inject doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16649413/spring-annotation-inject-doesnt-work)

i remove my new operator for all classes which is calling my applicationproperties.java

```
@Service
public class ADAuthenticatorService {

private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ADAuthenticatorService.class);
private final static long DIFF_NET_JAVA_FOR_DATE_AND_TIMES = 11644473600000L;

@Inject
ADContext adContext;



/**
 * AD authentication
 * 
 * @param UserID,
 *            AD User ID
 * @param Password,
 *            AD Password
 * @return ADProfile
 */
@Inject
ApplicationProperties applicationProperties;
public ADProfile authenticate(String UserID, String Password) throws Exception {

    ADContext context = adContext.getDefaultContext(applicationProperties);
    return authenticate(context, UserID, Password);

}
```

in my ADContext i put @component on the top of my Class name, and added @Sevice annotation on the top of ADAuthenticatorService

then my

```
@Inject
ApplicationProperties applicationProperties;
```

is working flawlessly

just posting this answer so any noob like me at outside can benefit this lol