# jhipster java tests failing - application properties

Tags: java, spring-boot, testing, properties, jhipster

I have generated a jhipster monolithic app. I have created a class to connect with the AWS S3 and upload a file there. I defined the properties in .yml file. Here everything works fine.

When I am trying to run the provided tests, most of them are failing with the following error:

**Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 's3AutoConfig': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'aws.endpoint.url' in value "${aws.endpoint.url}"**

S3AutoConfig is the class which uses the properties.
I checked jhipster's documenation and several posts, like the one below:
[Adding applicationproperties in Jhipster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42871453/adding-applicationproperties-in-jhipster)

which mention that you should provide the properties in the ApplicationProperties class (seems a bit redundant).

I defined the properties also in the java class, but the tests are still failing with the same error above.

How should I define the properties, so they are picked up by the tests? Is it necessary to provide them also in the java class as some posts suggest?

[image: properties]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your implementation cannot work because you are defining `Aws` class within `ApplicationProperties` which means that your AWS properties will be prefixed by `application`, so for example `application.aws.endpoint.url` which does not match your `application*.yml` structure and this is why you get this error.

You should extract `Aws` class and its inner classes to its own file (Aws.java) and use prefix "aws".
Also, it would probably better named as `AwsProperties`.

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "aws", ignoreUnknownFields = false)
public class Aws {
```

Then the second point about tests is that they are using a different classpath than main class so you should ensure that you define these properties also in `src/test/resources/config/application.yml`

Comment: Thank you Gaël! Yes, shame on me, I was expecting that tests would have their own separate .yml file but I somehow did not see it, thanks for the explanation, tests are working fine again :)