# Spring Service injection is Null when using Pojo instead of Rest Controller

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I'm  trying to use Spring and Jhipster to access some Database. I want to use a service, using injection.

When using a rest Controller, I have no problem, but when I'm trying to use an injected service in a pojo, this service is null.

```
@RestController
public class TheRestController {

    @Autowired
    protected TheService theService;

    @RequestMapping("/test")
    public void test() {

        if (theService == null) {
            System.out.println("rest : null");
        }
        {
            System.out.println("Rest : service is not null");
        }

        System.out.println("Call Pojo ");

        Pojo pojo = new Pojo();
        pojo.process();
    }
}
```

The service is not null and could be used to acces to the database.
But when I try to use the Pojo, in the rest controller or directly in the main(), the Service is null.

My Pojo is exactly the same as the Rest controller :

```
public class Pojo  {

    @Autowired
    protected TheService theService;     // this one is allways null.

    public void process(){
        if (theService == null){
            System.out.println( "POJO : null" );
        }else{
            System.out.println("POJO : service is not null");
        }
    }
}
```

When sending a request, I have the output :

```
Rest : service is not null
Call Pojo 
POJO : null
```

I tried with @Autowired, @Resource and @Inject, same result.

how can I access to theService in a Pojo (without allways passing it as an a parameter) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring container can only manage beans (objects) created within that container - if you create an object using `new` keyword, Spring has no way to inject the dependencies (it doesn't even know that the object exists). If you want to use dependencies in `main()`, you have to:

- Declare the Pojo in the Spring configuration, or annotate it as `@Component` or `@Service`
- Create a new Spring container in your main:

  ```
  AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
  context.register("path.to.your.package");
  context.refresh();
  ```
- Get the (Spring-managed) instance of Pojo:

  ```
  Pojo myPojo = context.getBean(Pojo.class);
  ```

Comment: Great ! I was close to understand Spring and dependency injection, and it seems that your answer help me a lot.

I should defined all component as "Component", then I shall not build them using "new" but as field, using Inject.

Bonus question : shall I use Inject or Autowired ? 

or it does not matter ?

Comment: @GaspardP see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7142622/what-is-the-difference-between-inject-and-autowired-in-spring-framework-which

Answer (score 0):

I'll just add to Jiri's answer (which I don't recommend unless Pojo is a singleton).

You should be aware of lifecycles. If Pojo is not a singleton I don't recommend you use Spring to manage instances of Pojo or autowire or both (although it can be done it is slow and there is a difference between just autowiring and managing).

That is if **your creating Pojo per request you should NOT use Spring** to manage the wiring and creation of the object.

For general edification you can have beans automagically wired via normal object construction ie `new Pojo` through AspectJ and `@Configurable`. These beans are autowired by spring but not managed by spring.

Spring also supports managing and autowiring non-singleton beans ([see Spring scope](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes)) but I really do not recommend doing that.

Instead you should create singletons (spring managed component ie `@Service` or `@Component`) for creating non-singleton objects  like `Pojo`. This is called the Factory pattern.