# @Autowired does not work with @Configurable

Tags: spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection, nullpointerexception, autowired

I am trying to do an image upload API. I have a `ImageUpload` task as follows,

```
@Component
@Configurable(preConstruction = true)
@Scope(BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
public class ImageUploadTask implements Callable<JSONObject> {

 @Autowired
 private ImageUploadService imageUploadService;

 @Override
 public JSONObject call() throws Exception {
    .... 
    //Upload image via `imageUploadService`
   imageUploadService.getService().path('...').post('...'); // Getting null pointer here for imageUploadService which is a WebTarget

 }
}
```

The `ImageUploadService` looks like the below,

```
@Component
public class ImageUploadService {

@Inject
@EndPoint(name="imageservice") //Custom annotation, battle tested and works well for all other services
private WebTarget imageservice;

public WebTarget getService() {
    return imageservice;
 }
}
```

Here is the spring boot application class,

```
@ComponentScan
@EnableSpringConfigured
@EnableLoadTimeWeaving(aspectjWeaving=EnableLoadTimeWeaving.AspectJWeaving.ENABLED)
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class ImageApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

 @Bean
 public InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver loadTimeWeaver() throws Throwable   {
    InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver loadTimeWeaver = new InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver();
    return loadTimeWeaver;
 }

 @Override
 public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
    super.onStartup(servletContext);
    servletContext.addListener(new RequestContextListener());
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    SpringApplication.run(ImageApplication.class);
 }
}
```

Additional information :

- Spring version of dependencies are at 4.2.5.RELEASE
- `pom.xml` has dependencies added for `spring-aspects` and
  `spring-instrument`

I am getting a `NullPointerException` in `ImageUploadTask`. My suspicion is that `@Autowired` doesn't work as expected.

- Why wouldn't work and how do I fix this?
- Is it mandatory to use `@Autowired` only when I use `@Conigurable`, why not use `@Inject`? (though I tried it and getting same NPE)

Comment: where do you use the ImageUploadTask ?

Answer (score 1):

By default the autowiring for the `@Configurable` is *off* i.e. [Autowire.NO](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Autowire.html#NO) beacuse of which the `imageUploadService` is `null`

Thus update the code to explicity enable it either as [BY_NAME](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Autowire.html#BY_NAME) or [BY_TYPE](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Autowire.html#BY_TYPE) as below.

```
@Component
@Configurable(preConstruction = true, autowire = Autowire.BY_NAME)
@Scope(BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
public class ImageUploadTask implements Callable<JSONObject> { .... }
```

Rest of the configuration viz. enabling load time weaving seems fine.

Also regarding `@Inject` annotation have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7144137/1910582) which pretty much explains the difference (*or similarity perhaps*)