# Equivalent of @Bean without Spring

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, javabeans

How to make the same thing without Spring ?
I don't know how to declare the bean using specific constructor.

Usually I would do it with Spring this way, but right now I can't use Spring.

```
@Configuration
public class ClientConfig {
    @Bean
    public MyApi myApi() {
        return Feign.builder().target(MyApi.class, myUrl);
    }
}
```

And use injection in another class.

```
public class AnotherClass {
    @Inject
    MyApi myApi;
}
```

How to "declare" the bean?
Today I'm using a singleton and it is 'ugly', so thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: Did you try with @Inject annotation (Java EE CDI Dependency Injection)

Comment: https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/05/java-ee-cdi-dependency-injection-inject-tutorial.html --> Probably this link helps you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7142622/what-is-the-difference-between-inject-and-autowired-in-spring-framework-which

Answer (score 1):

You can use producer method which creates desired injectable bean. It's good practice to put producer methods in separated bean:

```
@Dependent
public class Resources {

    @Produces
    @Default  
    public MyApi myApi() {
        return Feign.builder().target(MyApi.class, myUrl);
    }
}
```

you can use `@Inject MyApi myApi` anywhere you need it then.

For more info see the CDI documentation http://weld.cdi-spec.org/.