# Should @Inject and @Autowired ever be explicitly declared?

Tags: java, spring, autowired

These annotations are used in Spring to managed IoC. 
For every possible use of these, is there some case when we don't need to declare they because Spring already would detect Its use?

Is preferable to use @Inject than @Autowired because It is specified from Java and It's newer?

Comment: You need to declare them when you use Field injection. With Constructor injection you can not declare them

Comment: Please checkout the extensive discussion here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7142622/what-is-the-difference-between-inject-and-autowired-in-spring-framework-which

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMO such annotations should always be explicitly declared.  Spring does not require it for constructor DI.  However, I would avoid doing anything framework specific, unless it is required.  That being said, I would use the javax Inject annotation and be explicit everywhere.

Comment: No need to bother with annotating singleton constructors.

Comment: @chrylis Excluding the annotation would be framework specific.