# What is the default bean scope if we use @Inject with @Component?

Tags: spring, spring-annotations, jsr330

I know the default bean scope is singleton when we use `@Autowired` with `@Component`.

But what if we use JSR-330's `@Inject` with spring's `@Component` (without using `@Scope` or `@Singleton`)?

Comment: The scope of components doesn't depend on which annotation you use to inject them. A Spring bean is a singleton by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no difference between  [@Inject or @Autowired](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7142622/what-is-the-difference-between-inject-and-autowired-in-spring-framework-which)

> two annotations works the same way as Spring has decided to support some JSR-299  annotations in addition to their own

Note [JSR-299](http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/what_is_the_relation_between) is built on top of JSR-330

> JSR-299 (Java Contexts and Dependency Injection), with Gavin King as lead, uses JSR-330 as base and enhances it significantly with modularization, cross cutting aspects (decorators, interceptors), custom scopes, or type safe injection capabilities. JSR-299 is layered on top of JSR-330

All [spring beans](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch04s04.html), as `@Component`, are by default singletons

> singleton bean is quite different from the Singleton pattern as defined in the seminal Gang of Four (GoF) patterns book. The GoF Singleton hard codes the scope of an object such that one and only one instance of a particular class will ever be created per ClassLoader. The scope of the Spring singleton is best described as per container and per bean. This means that if you define one bean for a particular class in a single Spring container, then the Spring container will create one and only one instance of the class defined by that bean definition. **The singleton scope is the default scope in Spring**