# Mockito mock is not injected into service class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, unit-testing, mockito

I am currently writing a test in which I am trying to work with a mocked service. However my mocked response is not returned as expected.
Below is shortened version of my test class.

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@Testcontainers
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class ParentServiceTest {

    @InjectMocks
    @Autowired
    private ParentService parentService;

    @Mock
    private ChildService childService;

    @BeforeEach
    public void init(){
        MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);
        Mockito.doReturn(otherDto).when(childService).getResponse(Mockito.any(String.class), Mockito.any(DTO.class));
    }

    @Test
    public void createAnswerTEST_Successful(){
        OtherDTO otherDto = parentService.doSomething(someString, dto);
    }
}
```

And this is how ParentService looks like:

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ParentService{

    private final ChildService childService;

    public OtherDTO doSomething(String someString, DTO dto){
        //HERE THE MOCKED OBJECT SHOULD BE RECEIVED
        OtherDTO otherDTO = childService.getResponse(someString, someDTO)
    }

}
```

And this is ChildService:

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ChildService {

    public OtherDTO getResponse(String someString, DTO someDto){
        return otherDTO
    }

}
```

What I can see is the following:
When I debug the test and stop before the function call I can see in my debugger something like `ChildService childService = {ChildService@21915}` and also inside my ParentService the following `ChildService childService = {ChildService@21990}` so I can see that in fact the mock is really not injected as the ChildService instance in the ParentService is different from the mock.

Comment: why are you trying to Autowire that service?

Comment: Ditch the mockito stuff, replace `@Mock` with `@Mockbean` and re-run. Or ditch the spring stuff in your test and use only mockito. You are now wrongly mixing both.

Comment: Be careful with `@MockBean` because it means one test will nead it's own unique application context (tests with `@MockBean` cannot share the application context with other tests). Personally I prefer to avoid `@MockBean` because it causes issues. Some of this discussed [here](https://filip-prochazka.com/blog/mockbean-is-an-anti-pattern)

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the **@Autowired** from **ParentService** since **@InjectMocks** is already instantiating the object.

For more details on the difference between @Autowired and @InjectMocks, you can refer to this Stack Overflow post: [Difference between @InjectMocks and @Autowired usage in Mockito.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7142622/what-is-the-difference-between-inject-and-autowired-in-spring-framework-which)

Answer (score 0):

1. **@InjectMocks** is a mockito annotation used to inject all created mocks into it. **@Autowired** is a spring annotation for DI. You should use only **@InjectMocks** here.
2. **@SpringBootTest** is an annotation for integration tests and is used to load Spring context. If you are writing a unit test with Mockito, you don't need to load the whole Spring context.
3. **MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this)** is redundant as you have already **@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)**.
4. You need to declare and initialize otherDto before setting the mock behavior.
5. Your test method does not have any assertions.
6. Could be issues with **@Testcontainer**s for mockito testing as it using more with integrations tests.

Here's a revised version of your test class considering all this mentions:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class ParentServiceTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private ParentService parentService;

    @Mock
    private ChildService childService;

    private OtherDTO otherDto;

    @BeforeEach
    public void init(){
        otherDto = new OtherDTO();
        Mockito.doReturn(otherDto).when(childService).getResponse(Mockito.any(String.class), Mockito.any(DTO.class));
    }

    @Test
    public void createAnswerTEST_Successful(){
        String someString = "testString";
        DTO dto = new DTO();
        OtherDTO result = parentService.doSomething(someString, dto);
        assertNotNull(result);
        assertEquals(otherDto, result);
    }
}
```